# What is the usage of the magic methods __construct() and __destruct(). Are they always required?

Tags: php

What is the usage of the magic methods __construct() and __destruct(). Are they always required?

Need a nice simple answer to this, it's a little confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About `__construct()`, it gives you the possibility to do some stuff with your newly created object **and** to overwrite the `__construct()` method of a parent class.

So it might not be required (neither are), but if a class extends another class, it might be required to add for example a constructor to avoid the automatic calling of a parent constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the simple explanation, what about the __destruct(), can you describe that in a simple manner too please?

Comment: @user1383080 I don't have that much use for `__destruct()`, it does what you tell it to do when you destroy your object, which in my case is almost always when the script ends and when I don't want to do anything else anyway...

Answer (score 2):

They are not required.
Construct is called upon initialization, that is when the object is created/constructed.
Destruct is called on clean up.

**Example:**

```
class Foo
{
    function __construct()
    {
        echo "start";
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        echo "end";
    }
}

$foo = new Foo(); // outputs start
echo ' : ';
unset( $foo );    // outputs end
echo ' ! ';
```

Above snippet outputs `start : end !`. If we don't use `unset` the destructor will still be called in the end of the script when cleaning up, the output would then be: `start :  ! end`

**Link**

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: @ArshadHussain Should work for you. Try the snippet here: http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: The output "end" also occuring when we are not using unset( $foo );

Comment: well yes, all instances are destroyed on cleanup. I just used `unset` to visualize the process better. See the updated answer for some additional explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The most common use I have for construct is to initialise class variables to a default value. I've not had a need to use destruct yet though.